# Angular 2 Pattern Validator reporting invalid incorrectly...?

Tags: regex, forms, angular, typescript

I'm working with a form for US phone numbers:

```
let phoneRegEx = '^\([1-9]{3}\)\s{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$';

class PhoneFormComponent {

    ...

    buildForm(): void {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          number: [
            this.phone ? this.phoneNumberPipe.transform(this.phone.number) : '', [
              Validators.required,
              Validators.pattern(phoneRegEx),
            ]
          ]
        });
    }
}
```

I also have a Pipe that formats the phone number to my liking:

```
@Pipe({name: 'phoneNumber'})
export class PhoneNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (!value) return value;

    let areaCode = value.substring(0, 3);
    let prefix = value.substring(3, 6);
    let number = value.substring(6);

    return `(${areaCode}) ${prefix}-${number}`;
  }
}
```

Phone numbers numbers are stored as a string with no spaces or formatting in the API that I am required to access, so I'm leveraging the pipe to format the phone number as provided by the service when populating the form, and then matching the same pattern for input. I strip out the formatting when supplying the value back to the API.

According to regex101.com, my regex should be working as expected: https://regex101.com/r/9TRysJ/1, e.g. (111) 111-1111 *should be valid*.

However, my Angular form always reports that the value for the phone field is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may use `let phoneRegEx = '^\\([1-9]{3}\\)\\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$';` and the `^` and `$` can be omitted as they will be added by default.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about the start and end characters. Your adjustments to the regex work as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*I don't Know Angular*

**But it REGEXP should Work.**

```
\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3})\-(\d{4})
```

**Result:**

```
Full match  0-14 `(123) 456-7890`
Group 1.    1-4 `123`
Group 2.    6-9 `456`
Group 3.    10-14 `7890`
```

*I'm basically separating each value into a group.*

**Then u can use**

```
($1) $2-$3
```

**Explanation:**

```
$1 = 123
$2 = 456
$3 = 7890
```

*Note:* $0 => Full Match (123) 456-7890